# libgdal.so.20 issue centos rgdal

Tags: centos6, gdal, rstudio-server, rgdal

Can someone help me to understanding what is the problem of rgdal ?

I installed gdal 2 for centos 6 64 bits but i didn't succeed to install rgdal.
I tried to figure out what is the issue but i didn't found anything useful on the internet .

this is Rstudio-server console:

```
 install.packages("rgdal")
 Installing package into ‘/home/admin/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
 (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
 essai de l'URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rgdal_1.2-18.tar.gz'
 Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1650578 bytes (1.6 MB)
  ==================================================
 downloaded 1.6 MB

 * installing *source* package ‘rgdal’ ...
 ** package ‘rgdal’ correctement décompressé et sommes MD5 vérifiées
 configure: CC: gcc -m64 -std=gnu99
 configure: CXX: g++ -m64
 configure: rgdal: 1.2-18
 checking for /usr/bin/svnversion... yes
 configure: svn revision: 718
 checking for gdal-config... /usr/local/bin/gdal-config
 checking gdal-config usability... yes
 configure: GDAL: 2.2.3
 checking GDAL version >= 1.6.3... yes
 checking gdal: linking with --libs only... yes
 checking GDAL: /usr/local/share/gdal/pcs.csv readable... yes
 configure: -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-        protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fpic -fPIC  -I/usr/local/include
  checking proj_api.h presence and usability... yes
 ./proj_conf_test1: error while loading shared libraries: libgdal.so.20:   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
  checking PROJ.4 version: ... < 4.8.0
./configure: line 2030: test: -eq: unary operator expected
  ./configure: line 2035: test: -ge: unary operator expected
  ./configure: line 2063: test: -ge: unary operator expected
  ./proj_conf_test2: error while loading shared libraries: libgdal.so.20:                cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
  checking PROJ.4: epsg found and readable... yes
  ./configure: line 2138: test: -ge: unary operator expected
  ./proj_conf_test3: error while loading shared libraries: libgdal.so.20:    cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
  checking PROJ.4: conus found and readable... yes
  configure: Package CPP flags:  -I/usr/local/include
  configure: Package LIBS:  -L/usr/local/lib -lgdal -lproj
  configure: creating ./config.status
  config.status: creating src/Makevars
  ** libs
  ogr_geom.cpp:39: attention : ‘mp_count_k0’ may be used uninitialized in this function

  ** R
  ** data
  ** inst
  ** preparing package for lazy loading
  ** help
  *** installing help indices
    converting help for package ‘rgdal’
      finding HTML links ... fini
      CRS-class                               html  
  ...
     closeDataset-methods                    html  
     displayDataset                          html  
     llgrid                                  html  
     Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpTT9ff6/R.INSTALL19d55c4b60f4/rgdal/man/llgrid.Rd:11: missing file link ‘Spatial’
     Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpTT9ff6/R.INSTALL19d55c4b60f4/rgdal/man/llgrid.Rd:16: missing file link ‘gridat’
     Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpTT9ff6/R.INSTALL19d55c4b60f4/rgdal/man/llgrid.Rd:17: missing file link ‘gridat’
         make_EPSG                               html  
         nor2k                                   html  
         projInfo                                html  
         project                                 html  
         readGDAL                                html  
     Rd warning: /tmp/RtmpTT9ff6/R.INSTALL19d55c4b60f4/rgdal/man/readGDAL.Rd:136: missing file link ‘flipVertical’
         readOGR                                 html  
         showWKT                                 html  
         spTransform-methods                     html  
         wrappers                                html  
         writeOGR                                html  
     ** building package indices
     ** installing vignettes
     ** testing if installed package can be loaded
     Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rgdal’ in          dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
      impossible de charger l'objet partagé '/home/admin/R/x86_64-redhat-         linux-gnu-library/3.4/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so':
       libgdal.so.20: Ne peut ouvrir le fichier d'objet partagé: Aucun    fichier ou dossier de ce type
  Erreur : le chargement a échoué
 Exécution arrêtée
     ERROR: loading failed
     * removing ‘/home/admin/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rgdal’
 Warning in install.packages :
   installation of package ‘rgdal’ had non-zero exit status

     The downloaded source packages are in
         ‘/tmp/RtmpBon7nM/downloaded_packages’
```

I tried to install dependencies of gdal and copying libgdal.so.20 to /user/lib64/ogdi whithout any success !*

Thank you for you help

Comment: Missing `libgdal.so` from gdal2 ? ... I.e. libgdal.so is the file required by `rgdal` ....  How did you install gdal2 ?

Comment: I built it from source .tar because when you try to install it using `yum install` it will install version gdal1 .  This is what i got when i tried to search for this lib 
`[root@brain ~]# locate libgdal.so
/root/gdal-2.2.3/.libs/libgdal.so
/root/gdal-2.2.3/.libs/libgdal.so.20
/root/gdal-2.2.3/.libs/libgdal.so.20.3.2
/usr/lib64/libgdal.so
/usr/lib64/libgdal.so.1
/usr/lib64/libgdal.so.1.14.3
/usr/lib64/ogdi/libgdal.so
/usr/lib64/ogdi/libgdal.so.20
/usr/local/lib/libgdal.so
/usr/local/lib/libgdal.so.20
/usr/local/lib/libgdal.so.20.3.2
`

Comment: libgdal-2.x.x must be installed with : `configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 && make` ... `# make install` ... in order to be found by Rgdal.

Comment: thank you for you help @knud ! actually the solution was so simple ! I just copied these libraries to 64 folder `cp /usr/local/lib/libgdal.so.20* /usr/lib64/` and everything worked fine !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was so simple !
CentOS can't find these libraries and I just copied these libraries to 64 folder .

`cp /usr/local/lib/libgdal.so.20* /usr/lib64/`

and everything work like a magic !

Comment: I love you, thank you so much! I have been on it for too long!

Answer (score 1):

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
it does work